# Help me understand a comment and downvote that a user made on my answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes

https://superuser.com/a/963738/99549

On a windows 10 question I gave the above answer, only known to work in earlier versions. I got an (seemingly authoritative?) downvote saying:

"answer should be posted with property and not using legacy os properties as parameter. your answer is About previous versions tag is clear Windows 10."

Now first of all the grammar and casing of this answer is lacking and more importantly, I don't know what is meant with "should be posted with property".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A few observations:

- The user who posted that comment may or may not be the person who dropped a downvote.
- That user has 1636 reputation, which isn't a *whole* lot, and is relatively easy to get.
- Just because one user posts a comment, whether or not they have a lot of rep, doesn't mean they're right, authoritative, or representative of the views of the site moderators or Stack Exchange. However, insofar as reputation has significance about the quality of a user's contributions to the site and the degree to which they're a veteran contributor, 1636 reputation is really not enough to draw any conclusions about authoritativeness.
- Users who can only speak (or, more properly, write in) "broken English" are common on Stack Exchange. If you have difficulty understanding what they mean, *ask them what they mean*.
- The person who replied to you had posted an answer of his own to the same question, so he might be thereby motivated to downvote your answer to make his look better, even if he didn't have any legitimate reason to downvote your answer (and I can't tell if he did or not, based on his broken English comment).

**That said**, as far as the actual content of your answer, there are some problems with it:

- The question is about **Windows 10**. It says so by using the tag [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).
- Your answer is about earlier versions of Windows (7/8/8.1). By not testing your answer on Windows 10, you're doing a disservice to the querant. If you don't know if your method works or not on Windows 10, either test it, or don't post it as an answer (a comment might be OK). An *answer* means, "I know (with fairly good certainty) how to do this and **this is how**". You *may* include disclaimers about uncertainty in an answer, but your answer does not address whether you tried it on Windows 10, and how sure you are of it working or not working on Windows 10.

Ultimately, I believe the *upvoted* answer (the one that presently has a score of 1 and basically says "You *can't* turn off automatic updates) is the more correct answer, especially as it applies to Windows 10 Home. However, you or someone else would need to actually *try* your answer to see if it works before claiming it as an answer.

In general, when you have problems understanding the reasoning of other users, it's better to **ask them directly** (in comments), rather than making a meta post about it. Especially since, in this case, you didn't even attempt to clarify his position with him. We can offer a guess as to his intentions, but not even a moderator can tell you who downvoted the post, and the best person for explaining the meaning of a comment is the original person who wrote it.

To wrap up: I feel that the current score of -1 of your answer is justified, even though I myself did not drop that downvote. I'm not going to downvote it any further, though. It's just a poorly researched answer that doesn't answer the actual question about *Windows 10* but rather relies on an old version's behavior and apparently just assumes it'll be the same on Windows 10 (which, as it turns out, it's really not the same).

Comment: I know I am not supposed to make "thanks" style comments, but I really want to tell you how grateful I am for your effort in clarifying this and improving this meta question. I am looking forward to hopefully becoming better at answering questions.

Comment: "Thanks" style comments in Meta are fine... :)

Comment: @masterxilo - You should go ahead and fix the problems with your answer to that question.  So the person who voted on the answer, can reverse the downvote, after you address their concerns.  The comment basically is indicating, the question is about Windows 10, so an answer on any other version of Windows except Windows 10 is not helpful.  I also have voted on the answer, the answer can be fixed, so feel free to do that.

Comment: +1, especially for "*If you have difficulty understanding what they mean, ask them what they mean.*".

Answer (score 11):

I'll answer your question mate, it is simply:

1. I read the tag which was [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).
2. I read the question.
3. I read all of the answers.
4. I saw your answer and noticed you were giving a method that worked in Windows 7, 8, and 8.1.
5. I tried to post what I thought about your answer (sorry if it was grammatically incorrect; I'm not a native English speaker) and I basically meant to suggest that you post an answer when you are sure about it and not based on how this worked in previous versions of Windows.

When first using SU I make mistakes but am following all of the rules now. I'm very exited about this community and if I hurt your feelings I'm very very sorry. I have no problem downvoting if I think it's deserved and you shouldn't take a downvote as personal attack. I'll tell you why:

I vote down when I really think the answer does not provide a candidate answer. I do not vote down a post for technical inaccuracies or errors. In other words, I do not vote down if you answer a question about how to care an apple, even if the method is wrong, but I'll vote down if you answer about grapes when the user is asking about apples. However, if you edit your post and provide an answer about apples, if I like I will upvote. So I have the choice to stay downvoting neutral or upvoting. I'm not a troll of users or points trying to downvote a question, only seeking to damage another user's reputation, because that's really **** (you can guess what I wrote).

As another example, I've contributed some answers where I was really wrong and ended up deleting them despite their having upvotes.

So I suggest you to do not consider a downvote a personal attack because it isn't.

Do not think I or someone else is trying to attack your reputation. Some guys here have 100s of points and they are very very skilled with imba acknowledgements but maybe they are not focused on points, so do not take the reputation as a skill-meter.

Greetings and peace.

Comment: Well said Franscisco Tapia.  I've applied some grammatical finesse to your post but please review it to make sure I've kept to your intentions.

Comment: Its OK I wanted to left in clear I do not try to Hurt no one because this site improved my skills a lot, inclusive, for example user @ramhound he haves a very acid comments but I always took his comments are constructive because they really are and I Know he doesn't want to Hurt no one, and he is a very smart and skilled guy.  And is how is and I respect hin, ps. Im proud of my broken English I learn for my self not using año translator btw XD

Comment: @FranciscoTapia - You shouldn't consider my comments as "acid" they are "to the point", but to understand that, you have to understand the way I communicate overall.  There is an entire model that describes how I communicate, it boils down to the fact, "I say what I say and mean what I say" and since I am a low context person there isn't a high context meaning to what I say.  I choose my words and what I say very carefully, I of course as a human get emotional, but normally my initial comments are without emotion.

Comment: Yeah I Know :), that I mean, some ppl are more sensitive and took the neutral or no emotional comments as an attack then they are not.